# Eclipse PDT Code folding

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-pdt

I would like to fold {} brackets  i.e if/else, for, while, foreach... sections in eclipse pdt. How can i do it. I don't see any options in settings.

Comment: As far as I know, there's no such built-in functionality for PHP code formatting :(

Comment: Coffee-Bytes for Eclipse 3.6 & higher: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8534542/what-code-folding-plugins-work-on-eclipse-3-6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eclipse PDT doesnt posses it Try Aptana instead of Eclipse PDT it provides basic-intermediary folding support

Comment: I've always used Aptana, never knew PDT (or Eclipse!) didn't support such a fundamental feature.

Comment: yeah @BoltClock it's such a basic feature why cant they add it

Comment: The feature is available in Zend Studio, which is based off Eclipse + PDT. However, Zend also maintains PDT for Eclipse, so they don't want PDT to be competing their overpriced Zend Studio.

Answer (score -1):

Use Notepad++, it has the best folding. To be most productive have 2 screens open one with Eclipse and another with Notepad++ with the same code. It is much faster to edit in notepad++ however Eclipse provides much better functionality for debugging, code checks, etc..