# javadoc folding plugin for eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, intellij-idea, javadoc

My co-worker is using Idea and by default the javadocs are folded in (there is a good reason for it 99,9% of the time they are useless and generated by a plugin). is there any eclipse plugin written in Java that allows me to have javadocs folder by default?

Comment: It may be helpful i guess:

Coffee-Bytes for Eclipse 3.6 & higher: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8534542/what-code-folding-plugins-work-on-eclipse-3-6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understood you well, `Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Folding -> Comments` is what you want.