# Eclipse: Java: Folding Code Blocks Smaller Than A Method

Tags: java, eclipse, code-folding

I'm new to Eclipse.

I haven't found a way to fold blocks of code in Java smaller than a method.

I have a legacy project to maintain with huge and frequent nested conditionals.  Refractoring is not an option at this point.

I searched StackOverflow, there was some mention of a plugin called Coffee-Bytes which enhances Eclipse code folding, but the GoogleCode site where it is hosted said the project is no longer being developed and there were no downloads to download.

Can anyone suggest an alternative?

I already have a better IDE ( Visual Slickedit ), but I am trying to get used to using Eclipse, at least for a while as it seems to be an industry standard.

Thanks

Comment: I read that post.  It is about getting folding enabled.  I have folding enabled, it just doesn't fold enough.  My questions is about how to get Eclipse to fold more.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8534542/what-code-folding-plugins-work-on-eclipse-3-6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Put the cursor in front of the code block to the left.  I used a long conditional
2. Press the  PageDown key with numlock on/off.

You do not get any graphical indication that anything is folded.

I had line number display enabled so I could see that a sequence of numbers were missing.