# Show only part of document in editor

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, editor, document, eclipse-pde

Is it possible to show only a part of a document in a (possible custom) Eclipse editor? There is [ITextViewer#setVisibleRegion](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/text/ITextViewer.html), but this only scrolls the viewport. I'd like to show only a partition of a given document or (alternatively) lock everything but a given region (i.e. make parts outside of this region non-editable).

Comment: It sounds like you might want an equivalent for Emacs' narrow-to-region.  Are you including approaches like programmatically editing the document (probably the copy you're displaying, not the original), say by including text-cookies to trigger folding, or does it need to be strictly the original data, using buffer positions for folding (like narrow-to-region)?

Comment: Programmatic editing is part of the task at hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try the Eclipse folding plugin at:

http://kosiara87.blogspot.com/2011/12/how-to-install-coffee-bytes-plugin-in.html

With a download at:

http://sites.google.com/site/bkosarzyckistorage1/eclipse-folding-plugin.tar.gz

It lets you define identifiers for start and end region, and then put them in your document to control visibility by region (apparently line based, rather than finer-grained, but that what most people tend to want).

In the "User Defined Regions" tab use e.g.:

```
Start identifier: region    End identifier: endregion
```

In code:

```
//region SomeName
your code
//endregion SomeName
```

There's a thread on this in [What code folding plugins work on Eclipse 3.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8534542/what-code-folding-plugins-work-on-eclipse-3-6)

I haven't used it myself but it might fit your needs.  It might also be incompatible with current versions of Eclipse - the page describing it is from about a year and a half ago.